# Retornar dados de duas tabelas idênticas [SQL] [Python]

Tags: python, sql, query

Olá, quero uma ajuda com consulta SQL.

Existem duas tabelas idênticas porém com dados registrados diferentes em cada uma.
Como posso fazer para pegar os dados das duas tabelas? Como se fossem dois selects em cada tabela?

Tipo: `select * tabela1`,`select * tabela2`

Porém gostaria que o retorno fosse apenas um.. Por enquanto sem nenhuma condição/comparação, apenas retornar todos os dados de ambas tabelas.

Estou programando em python, será que na programação consigo fazer isso? Acredito que sim mas acho que ficaria mais lento, certo?

Comment: Se consegui entender o resultado desejado tente UNION: `select * tabela1 UNION select * tabela2`. Talvez, dependendo do resultado desejado, seja necessário `UNION ALL`

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
TABELA1.*, 
TABELA2.* 
FROM TABELA1
FULL OUTER JOIN TABELA1 ON TABELA1.Chave = TABELA2.Chave
```

Você pode usar o UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABELA1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TABELA2
```

nesse caso o retorno de cada consulta ficará embaixo do outro, se quiser lado a lado, teria de ser feito uma sub-select com max, o que acredito que não vale a pena, será melhor usar o full outer join e filtrar o que você precisa.